# How to use ImgUr npm package to add images to an album

Tags: javascript, typescript, imgur

I'm using the [ImgUr NPM library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imgur) to upload my images.
After that I would like to add the uploaded images to an album, say 'HelloWorld'.

Here is my code:

```
export async function uploadToImgUr(files: Buffer[]): Promise<string[]> {
    const uploadPromises = files.map(async (file) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', file);

        const response = await client.upload({
            image: file,
            type: 'stream',
        });

        // Add the uploaded image to the album, this is my guess, but not working
        const resp = await client.getAlbum(brand);
        resp.data.images.push(response.data);

        return response.data.link;
    });

    return Promise.all(uploadPromises);
}
```

How can I do it?